# Get an egg (item) that doesn't summon a chicken

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I searched for every tag possible on an egg *(item)* but I didn't find anything special to get an egg that will never spawn a chicken.
[image: tags]
these are all the visible tags on an item.egg + the command I used to get them (I runned that command when I dropped the egg on the ground)

so does anyone know how to `/give` or get an egg without the chance to spawn a chicken?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use a lever to control a piston that pushes a redstone block that activates a repeating command block? Wouldn't just the lever be enough?

Comment: just idc xD (I already changed it before I read this xD cause it was OP useless)

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible.

Eggs always have a chance to spawn a chicken. You could trace the egg and when it hits something, kill any chicken that appears at that location, but that's neither lag friendly, nor easy.

Could snowballs work instead?